# Codeigniter on insert update other tables depending radio button selected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i need a little Codeigniter/php/Mysql help, i have 3 mysql tables, item, batch and transactions. in transactions i have a column transaction_type which in my code i have 4 radio buttons: Incoming, Outgoing, Damaged and Expired.
i also have a column quantity in transaction, batch and Items tables, i want on insert to the transaction table if one had selected radio button Incoming, then the value in field quantity is updated by adding to column quantity in the two tables items and batch. and if radio button Outgoing or Damaged or Expired are selected, then the value in field quantity is updated by subtracting to column quantity in the two tables items and batch.

here is my insert script

```
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {

    $data['transaction_date'] = $this->input->post('transaction_date');
    $data['item'] = $this->input->post('item');
    $data['batch'] = $this->input->post('batch');
    $data['section'] = $this->input->post('section');
    $data['transaction_type'] = $this->input->post('transaction_type');
    $data['quantity'] = $this->input->post('quantity');
        $this->db->insert('transactions', $data);
      if($transaction_type == Incoming) {
        $prepared = $this->prepare("UPDATE items SET balance = quantity+$balance WHERE id=?");
        $this->execute($prepared, '');
    }elseif($transaction_type == Outgoing){
        $prepared = $this->prepare("UPDATE items SET balance = quantity-$balance WHERE id=?");
        $this->execute($prepared, '');
    }
     $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('items_issued_successfully'));
```

here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE `batches` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`supplier` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`batch_no` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`manufacturing_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`balance` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `item` (`item`),
KEY `supplier` (`supplier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `items` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`item` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`balance` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
`reorder_level` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`transaction_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`item` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`batch` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`section` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`transaction_type` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`quantity` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '1.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `item` (`item`),
KEY `batch` (`batch`),
KEY `section` (`section`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What issue are you getting?

Comment: like my idea is when i run an insert to the transaction view the insert goes well but it does not update the quantity columns of table ITEMS and BATCH

Comment: here are my tables

Answer (score 0):

May issue in condition you are checking with  `$transaction_type` but post data stored in `$data['transaction_type']`

try this:

```
  if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {

    $data['transaction_date'] = $this->input->post('transaction_date');
    $data['item'] = $this->input->post('item');
    $data['batch'] = $this->input->post('batch');
    $data['section'] = $this->input->post('section');
    $data['transaction_type'] = $this->input->post('transaction_type');
    $data['quantity'] = $this->input->post('quantity');
        $this->db->insert('transactions', $data);
      if($data['transaction_type'] == Incoming) {
        $prepared = $this->prepare("UPDATE items SET balance = quantity+$balance WHERE id=?");
        $this->execute($prepared, '');
    }elseif($data['transaction_type'] == Outgoing){
        $prepared = $this->prepare("UPDATE items SET balance = quantity-$balance WHERE id=?");
        $this->execute($prepared, '');
    }
     $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('items_issued_successfully'));
```